# In $\bigtriangleup OAB,\angle\mathrm{AOB}=90^\circ.$ Let C lie on segment $AB$ such that $\overrightarrow{OC}\;\perp\;\overrightarrow{AB}$.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, plane-geometry

I am stuck at proving the following question.

In $\bigtriangleup OAB,\angle\mathrm{AOB}=90^\circ.$ Let C be the point on the segment $AB$ such that $\overrightarrow{OC}\;\perp\;\overrightarrow{AB}$.

Show that

$\displaystyle\frac{\overrightarrow{\left|CA\right|}\;}{\overrightarrow{\left|CB\right|}}=\frac{\displaystyle\overrightarrow{\left|OA\right|}^2}{\displaystyle\overrightarrow{\left|OB\right|}^2}$

EDIT:
I got to $\overrightarrow{AC}\;=\lambda\;\overrightarrow{AB}$ and expressed $\overrightarrow{OC}\;$ in terms of $\overrightarrow{OA},\;\overrightarrow{OB}\;and\;\lambda$. I know $\overrightarrow{OC}\;.\;\overrightarrow{AB}\;=\;0$ but I do not know how to carry on

Comment: What sorts of things have you tried? If you put your attempts in the question we will better be able to help you.

Comment: I got to $\overrightarrow{AC}\;=\;\lambda\;\overrightarrow{AB\;}$ and expressed $\overrightarrow{OC}\;$ in terms of $\overrightarrow{OA}\;,\;\overrightarrow{OB}\;and\;\lambda$.
I know $\overrightarrow{OC}\;.\;\overrightarrow{AB}\;=\;0$, but I do not know how to continue anymore @CarlSchildkraut

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit that into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\Delta AOC\sim\Delta OBC,$ we obtain:
$$\frac{AC}{OC}=\frac{OC}{BC}=\frac{AO}{OB}.$$
Thus, $OC^2=AC\cdot BC$ and
$$\frac{AO^2}{BO^2}=\frac{AC^2}{OC^2}=\frac{AC^2}{AC\cdot BC}=\frac{AC}{BC}.$$
Also, you can end your idea.

Indeed, $$\vec{OC}=\vec{OA}+\lambda\vec{AB}=\vec{OA}+\lambda\left(\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}\right)=(1-\lambda)\vec{OA}+\lambda\vec{OB}$$ and since $\vec{OC}\cdot\vec{AB}=0$ we obtain:
$$\left((1-\lambda)\vec{OA}+\lambda\vec{OB}\right)\left(\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}\right)=0$$ or
$$-(1-\lambda)OA^2+\lambda OB^2=0$$ or
$$\lambda=\frac{OA^2}{OA^2+OB^2}=\frac{OA^2}{AB^2}.$$
Thus, $$AC=\lambda AB=\frac{OA^2}{AB},$$
$$BC=(1-\lambda)AB=\frac{OB^2}{AB}$$ and
$$\frac{AC}{BC}=\frac{OA^2}{OB^2}.$$

Comment: I don't quite get how you managed to get $BC=(1-\lambda)AB=\frac{OB^2}{AB}$
@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Did you type wrongly? Your answer for BC here and the one above is different @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: Yes, it should be $BC=AB-AC=AB-\frac{OA^2}{AB}=\frac{AB^2-OA^2}{AB}=\frac{OB^2}{AB}.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\triangle OAB\sim \triangle CAO\sim\triangle COB.$$

Can you see why? Can you see why that lets you conclude the result?

Comment: No, I don't really get it. Am i supposed to find some numerical value of $\lambda$ ? If so, how do I do it when I have no numbers other than that right angle to play with

Comment: @deviljones You can if you want - it's better to consider this problem geometrically than with vectors. Which part do you not see how to do (figuring out that these triangles are similar or why that finishes the problem)?

Comment: Using similar triangles to prove this just didn't cross my mind at all... :( But how do i go about doing it the vectors way?